# Java swing is not retrying methods after exceptions

Tags: java, swing

When an input of text is given in this method

```
private int random1DimGetNumeral(String textThatCausesError){
   int result = 2;
    try{ 
        result = Integer.parseInt(textThatCausesError);
    } catch (Exception inputError) {
        textPanel.setText("Input Error for Random Dimmension feild 1.\n");
    }
    return result;
}
```

for the parameter textThatCausesError, then later when the text is numeric, Ex "56". It still catches an exception and returns 2 instead. Is it that my catch is too generic?

Comment: Integer.parseInt(textThatCausesError); is correct... you have been trying with another value for sure!

Comment: Just a guess: have you checked for spaces before and after 56? E.g. " 56" or "56 ". Try `Integer.parseInt(textThatCausesError.trim())`.

Comment: You are catch is too broad (`Exception`), you should narrow it down to a more specific one (`NumberFormatException` in this case). However, that's not the problem with your code. The only thing that can happen is that your string is not parsable as an integer. [ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ](http://stackoverflow.com/users/982161/%ce%a6xoc%c4%99-%ec%9b%83-%d0%9fepe%c3%bapa-%e3%83%84) enumerated the possible reasons in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41955933/507738).

Comment: You are right @MCEmperor I changed the answer to reflect that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt(textThatCausesError);` is correct, the only options to get an exception are:

- you are trying with a string 
  that is not representing an integer
- OR you are trying  with a string number that in overflowing the int capacity (32 bits)after trying the parsing

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
class Pong {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Pong pong = new Pong();
        System.out.println(pong.random1DimGetNumeral("56"));
    }

    private int random1DimGetNumeral(String textThatCausesError){
       int result = 2;
        try{ 
            result = Integer.parseInt(textThatCausesError);
        } catch (Exception inputError) {
            System.out.println("Input Error for Random Dimmension feild 1.\n");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```